# R: Making "as.factor" on a dataset dynamically

Tags: r

lets say I have the following dataset ds:

```
a, b, c, d, ...
1, 1, 1, 1, ...
0, 1, 0, 1, ...
1, 0, 1, 1, ...
0, 0, 1, 1, ...
1, 0, 0, 0, ...
```

now in order to make the column a as.factor all i have to do is:

```
ds$a <- as.factor(ds$a)
```

problem is when I dont know how many columns I have. So I thought going with a for loop over `length(ds)` but i cannot access ds$a dynamically. I've tried `ds[names(ds)[i]] <- as.factor(ds[names(ds)[i]])` but im getting the following error:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Can anyone shed some light over this?

Another problem that I've solved unelegantly is the following: lets say I dont want the first column and the last column to be affected. what I've done is

```
df[,3:length(engdata) - 1] <- lapply(df[,3:length(df) - 1], as.factor)
```

Is there an elegant way to deal with this?

Comment: `DF[] <- lapply(DF, as.factor)`

Comment: Thanks! I've reedit the question and add another level of complexity I'd like to solve elegantly.

Comment: @EranMoshe Roland's reply will still solve the problem but you might subset the data to get there. For example: data(mtcars)
mtcars[,c('mpg','cyl')]<-lapply(mtcars[,c('mpg','cyl')],as.factor)

Comment: Problem is i dont know the names of the columns.. I just know when I want to start making them as factors (Lets say from the 3rd column untill the 7th column. and the rest needs to remain untouched. As you see I've solved it but it looks quite unelegant.. I wonder if theres a beautiful solution like Ronalds solution to the simplier problem.

Comment: for unknown column names: ds[names(ds)[2:3]] <- lapply(ds[names(ds)[2:3]], as.factor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the indices of your columns you can do:

```
ds[names(ds)[2:3]] <- lapply(ds[names(ds)[2:3]], as.factor)
```

(Using the lapply-magic proposed by Robert in the comments)

your for loop would have also worked (you were just missing brackets)

```
for (i in 2:3) {
   ds[[names(ds)[i]]] <- as.factor(ds[[names(ds)[i]]])
}
```

note the difference between

```
> str(ds[2])
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
$ b: num  1 0 0 0 0
```

and

```
> str(ds[[2]])
num [1:5] 1 0 0 0 0
```